# Template error upgrading to underscore 1.7

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, upgrade, underscore.js-templating

When upgrading my web app from underscore 1.6 to 1.7, I receive the following error "list is not defined". When using underscore 1.6 it works perfectly. Any ideas?

```
//acquire the list template
$.get('tpl/listTpl.html', function(templates) {

//run underscore js on the list template and pass in the full collection of models
var template = _.template(templates, {list:app.collections.list.models});

//load the underscore template into the DOM
that.$el.html(template);
```

});

Comment: What is the exact error message? Is it coming from the template or the JavaScript? Are you sure that `app.collections.list.models` is set up like you expect it to be?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the 1.7.0 [changelog](http://underscorejs.org/#changelog):

> Underscore templates no longer accept an initial data object. _.template always returns a function now.

You will need to change your code to the following:

```
$.get('tpl/listTpl.html', function(templates) {
  var template = _.template(templates);
  var result = template({list:app.collections.list.models});
  that.$el.html(result);
});
```

Comment: I would recommend reading through the changelogs to catch any other breaking changes. Underscore doesn't use semantic versioning, so there absolutely are breaking changes between versions 1.6 and 1.7, though they don't affect everyone.

Comment: Thank you Ishmael! Worked a charm. Really appreciate your help.